# To create a list with sum of values from database for given condition in Django

Tags: django

I have the following model.

**models.py**

```
class WoCpt(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, null=False)
    comp = models.ForeignKey(Comp, null=False)
    proc = models.ForeignKey(Proc, null=False)
    points = models.IntegerField('Standard Time', null=False)
```

**Sample Database:**

```
[order, comp, proc, points]
[5,4,3,24]
[5,4,1,29]
[5,4,4,23]
[5,3,1,44]
[5,2,1,11]
[7,4,3,24]
[7,4,1,29]
[7,4,4,23]
[7,3,1,44]
[7,2,1,11]
```

**Problem**:

1. Need to calculate total points for order=5 and proc=1
2. After getting the sum, I need to create a list as below:
   (expectation - need to group the similar *proc* within a given *order* and prepare a list to pass it to view)

   [order, proc, points]
   [5,1,84]
   [5,3,24]
   [5,4,23]

Kindly help.

Comment: What did you try? Have you read the documentation? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#id5

Comment: Finding the sum alone is solved. Preparing a list is the problem now. I have updated the question. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write some logic your self. I am giving skeleton code for you. In your case you need to use django filters.

```
 order=5
 proc=1
 new_list = [order, proc, None]
 wocpt = WoCpt.objects.filter(order=order, proc=proc)
 new_list[2]=sum(row.points for row in wocpt)
 print new_list
 [5,1,84]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#filter

Answer (score 0):

No need to get all fancy in Python code. It can just as easily be done in the Django ORM with a single query.

```
>>> WoCpt.objects.values_list('order', 'proc').annotate(Sum('points'))
[(5,1,84), (5,3,24), (5,4,23)]
```

This will first group rows by their `order` and `proc` columns, and then annotate each row with the sum of points for all contained results. `values_list` will return a list of tuples, containing the values of the fields as ordered in the `values_list` parameters, followed by any annotated fields (so `('order', 'proc', 'points_sum')` in this case).

If you have these results, and you need the total points for a specific `order` and `proc`, you can use a function like this:

```
def total_points(l, order, proc):
    return [x for x in l if x[0] == order and x[1] == proc][2]
```

Comment: The Query works! I have a question regarding sending it to html. Is it possible to send it conventionally as data under 'object_list'? I may use the conventional approach of {% for x in object_list %} loop in the html.

Comment: Yes, that's certainly possible. While `values_list` acts as a list of tuples, it is still a queryset and can be used as such (except it doesn't contain models anymore). Also, any iterable (including queryset, lists, tuples, sets etc.) can be used in a for loop in the template.

Comment: My Bad, missed to watch it. While executing the query, order '7' & '5' appear in the result whereas the expectation is only '5'. How to add this condition to the query?